# NoClassDefFoundError on 3rd party lib's dependency when compiling Android app

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

Summary:

Updated an orphaned third-party library and compiled it successfully. When I use it in my Android project as a library, I get `NoClassDefFoundError` for one of the third-party library's dependencies that is not a dependency in my project (`javax.ws.rs.core.Configuration`).

---

Elaboration:

My Android application (Kotlin) needs to use a third party library (Java, connects to an API). The 3PL is an orphaned project on Github, can't connect to new version of the API.

I forked it and made a local copy. Updated it.

I compiled my modified 3rd party lib to a JAR (Build in Android Studio, it worked and produced the JAR file) and took the JAR file and added it to my Kotlin Android project as a library. Then I commented out the Gradle config that lists the previous version as a dependency to download.

Kotlin gives me no compile errors. However, when I run my unit tests, I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Configuration` as a runtime error.

This is not something I need in my Android project (and is not listed in my Android project's External Libraries), but it appears in the External Libraries of the third party lib.

My understanding was that if you compile a module, all you need to do to use that module in an app is include the module. I shouldn't need to include that module's dependencies as my own dependencies.

How do I fix this? I would prefer not to add javax.ws.* as a dependency in my own project since I don't use it except indirectly through the third party library.

Is there some special command I need to run to instruct Android Studio to include the dependencies in the JAR or what?

Comment: Do you run the release version of your app?

Comment: I run whatever happens when I hit "run project"

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue when I was trying to activate BarcodeScanner on Emulator, which is not possible as Emulator does not have it and it was throwing NoClassDefFoundError.
I used try...catch... to solve this issue while running app on Emulator. Once I installed it on real device it was not throwing this error for obvious. You can use it like this,

```
try {

    //Code that is throwing this error

} catch (NoClassDefFoundError ignore) {

    //Do nothing

}
```

If you have similar kind of issue, try this. It should work.

Comment: Turns out the class my code relied on doesn't even exist in Android's libs at all, so this does not fix my issue. My solution was to not use this library, but re-write it using Retrofit so it would work on Android devices.